# Depth map interpolation using QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I've produced an interpolation map using QGIS (a pond)

I have 40 points with a vdepthalue, and an additional 33 that represent the edge of the pound (depth 0).

My map is as follow:

[image]

and my TIN interpolation parameters are

[image]

Is this the most precise I can have with my number of points? Or can I aim at something like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried other interpolation methods like IDW? I guess that you already know that digital elevation model as raster is a starting point for creating contour lines vectors.

Comment: I can create the contours map, not a problem.
I'm wondering if the lack of precision of my depth map is only because of my small number of depth points

Comment: TIN creates just straight triangles between the points so without additional smoothing it does not look good. Try for example https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/v.surf.tps.html that is smooth by nature.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you can get a better interpolation using Kriging.
There is this plugin created by a Brazilian bloke. It is worth checking it out.

He made a video explaining how to use the plugin:

[Kriging with QGis on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFObnORruIY)

Below is a link to a video showing a step-by-step with some debugging if you have problems installing the plugin.

The debugging is basically a matter of you having all the Python extensions installed in your machine, specially "scikit-learn".

[Debugging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Vv1cAhiSVk)

In case you need to debug, you will have to go into the Brazilian bloke GitHub page:

[Author's Git Hub page](https://github.com/gustavowillam/SmartMapPlugin)

His GitHub page provide some answers to past issues reported

[Previous issues reported](https://github.com/gustavowillam/SmartMapPlugin/issues)

He also provided a tutorial and I am pretty sure Google can translate the page from Portuguese to English for you

[Tutorial](https://github.com/gustavowillam/SmartMapPlugin/wiki)